# Getting the correct hotel tariff from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to write some code to capture the correct hotel tariff based on the start and end date and perform auto-calculation. However, due to the differences in weekday prices and weekend prices, i have problems getting the correct tariff.

1 way i thought of is to show a gridview with radio buttons on the left for the user to select the correct tariff themselves. However it will defeat the purpose of me trying to do auto-calculation of the tariff.

Below is just a sample for demo purposes.
In C#, i will use prepared statements.

This is a sample SQL statement that i ran on SQL.

```
SELECT
    StartDate, EndDate, GrossPrice, RmType, Remarks
FROM
    HotelPriceFIT
WHERE
    HotelName='HotelA' AND RmType='SGL' AND DATE(EndDate) >='2018-02-01';
```

It is supposed to get the 9000 yen price.

Price list:

[image]

Would appreciate any form of help/assistance. 
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Jude,

Don't be afraid.

Take a bad query, and make it better.

Remember, to use range bound conditionals in your where clause, then you can begin to make it better.

```
SELECT 
    StartDate, EndDate, GrossPrice, RmType, Remarks 
FROM 
    HotelPriceFIT 
WHERE 
    HotelName = 'HotelA' AND 
    RmType='SGL' AND 
    EndDate >='2018-02-01' AND 
    StartDate <='2018-02-01'
;
```

Comment: Thanks Travis... Appreciate... having to come from a level 1 helpdesk background and suddenly doing C# programming single-handedly for an Intranet system is super tough... =(

Comment: i have a question, why did you put the EndDate in front of the StartDate? Is it because it will first check the EndDate then StartDate?

Comment: @Jude - The order wont make a difference, the only reason it is in this order is that you had already included the EndDate section, so I started from that existing spot and added the StartDate to complete the date range in the conditional statement.